# How to use shell in ConEmu console for windows 10 when I enabled shell in developer mode?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, shell, shell-script, conemu

I enabled the shell with this tutorial https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10

But if I have a shell script named `ca.sh` in a project root directory, I still can't run inside the project root with `./ca.sh` and error out with

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Anything I can do to enable shell mode inside ConEmu?

./ca.sh content:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Commit all with message: $1"
git status
git add *
git commit -m "chore(): $1"
git push origin master
```

I originally wrote something similar on MacOS and it runs well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me! ConEmu already has the Bash task... and yes, I am noobie, so I actually confused Bash with Shell.... because my script is actually bash script.

[image]

Click into the list with the Green background white + button, you will see the Bash as an option, actually Shell too!